# Configuring SMTP in IIS from Command Line

Tags: asp.net, msdeploy

I am relatively new to .NET. I wanted to know if there is a way to configure SMTP in IIS 5.1 from command line. I know there's a tool called Aapcmd.exe, but since it is only available to
IIS 7 or higher, I cant use it. However i came across some scripts in C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts on my system (which apparently are used for IIS administration)
......but coud'nt use them for SMTP configuration. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does IIS 5.1 (IIS on Windows XP) even come with an smtp service?

Comment: yup..it does, although you might need to explicitly install it from control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Joola... Turns out we can configure SMTP parameters using adsutil.vbs which is usally available at C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts or wherever you 'Inetpub' folder is....
I needed to change following parameters in a default SMTP setup:

```
 Connection Time Out for SMTP
 Windows Integrated Authentication
 Anonymous Authentication set False.
```

You can use adsutil.vbs to change these as mentioned below.

```
 Cscript adsutil.vbs set /smtpsvc/1/AuthAnonymous false
 Cscript adsutil.vbs set /smtpsvc/1/authntlm true
 Cscript adsutil.vbs set /smtpsvc/1/ConnectionTimeout 1200
```

Please note, instead of set one can also use the get option to view the current values...

Answer (score 0):

On iis.net you can find a [forum](http://forums.iis.net/1034.aspx) called 'Configuration & Scripting for IIS 5/6', one of the [threads](http://ttp://forums.iis.net/p/1172938/1961008.aspx#1961008) is 'Re: Configure SMTP Virtual Server by command line'.

Good luck.